# .htaccess rewrite to directory based on cookie

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

In my app I want to use *mod_rewrite* to have nice URLs, but also redirect logged in users (detected by `logged` cookie) to old not-so-nice URLs like this:

Nice URL: `mydomain.com/topic/12-name/`

Not-so-nice URL: `mydomain.com/other_topic?item_id=12&other=params`

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} logged
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /other_topic?item_id=$1&other=params [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /other_topic?item_id=$1&other=params [NC,L]
```

First one - redirect - works perfectly fine. Second one - rewrite - doesn't work at all. Any thoughts why?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly?

Comment: I should point out the problem with using permanent 301 redirects here. If a user is logged in, they'll get redirected to your Not-so-nice URL. But their browser will cache the 301 redirect. So when they log out, the browser will use the cached  permanent redirect regardless of cookie value. Thus the second rule is never seen by people with a cached redirect. Try clearing your browser cache then using a temporary 302 redirect for your logic to work.

Comment: Also why wouldn't you want the nice URL for everyone. Isn't that the purpose?

Comment: @PanamaJack - I'm trying to fix few things in old app without rebuilding i heavily. Nice URLs are mostly for SEO, but also to let me cache part of the website for not looged users on CDN (CloudFlare)

Comment: @Ultimater - thanks for your tips. Unfortunately its not the case. I was trying it on many browsers, also on incognito mode. But thanks for tip with 302 redirect. Will use it!

Comment: @w3d - now page address is: `mydomain.com/other_topic?item_id=12&other=params`. I want to rewrite it everywhere to `mydomain.com/topic/12-name/`. But also when user hit this address and is logged in I want to redirect him to old URL.

Comment: If a guest visits the Not-so-nice URL, you want it to redirect them to the Nice URL then silently rewrite the request back to the original URL?

Comment: @Ultimater - for not logged user - yes, you are right.

Comment: @Ultimater for logged user I want to be sure that he will always land on old URL

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should do what you want. Note that the `R` flag without a redirect code defaults to a temporary 302 redirect. You could also put `R=302` if that's clearer to you, I prefer `R` though since I remember easily that it defaults to a temporary redirect when remembering 302 is temporary and 301 is permanent is harder for me. It might make more sense to do this kind of redirecting from PHP though if you need to find the topic's "name".

```
RewriteEngine on

#First let's match logged in users and make sure they're visiting the ugly url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} logged
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /other_topic?item_id=$1&other=params [R,L]

#Next let's match guests and make sure they're visiting the clean url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !logged
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)item_id=(.*?)(?:$|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)other=.*?(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^/?other_topic/?$ /topic/%1-name/? [R,L]

#If we're still here, let's rewrite clean urls to our actual file
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /other_topic?item_id=$1&other=params [NC,L]
```